# How to completely delete user account?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I have Windows 7 as a member of a domain. Logged in as a local administrator I want to delete another local user account. In the `User Accounts` dialog I selected the account and clicked `Remove` and confirmed `Yes`.

The account is now gone from this list and can not be used for login, but the files and folders (`c:\Users\username`) and registry entries are still there.

Is there a simple way to remove all traces of that account?

[Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Delete-a-user-account) claims, quote:

> All files that were created under the user account will be deleted when you delete the account.

But apparently that did not happen.

Comment: registry entries are not considered "files". You can easily delete any folders and the contents of them that were left behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to remove all traces of that account?

No, not really. Removing all the files in their user profile is easy enough, but there will still be traces of the account all over. For example, even if you remove the user from the interface, there are multiple registry entry traces for the user.

So removing all traces is very difficult, and probably very unnecessary. If you just want their home folder removed, just go to System Properties / "Advanced System Settings" or "Advanced tab" / User Profiles > Settings, and delete the user profile (it may show up as unknown).

Comment: Thanks, it worked (removed the \Users\username folder, did not check registry entries yet).